# Two ModelForms in one CreateView

Tags: python, django

This probably have no sense, but it's better to get advice how to implement this behavior properly.
I have `User` model and two others (let it be `A` and `B`). Both `A` and `B` have `ForeignKey` to `User`. On `User` creation I also create `A` and `B` for this User:

```
def save(self, *args,  **kwargs):
    user_id = self.id
    super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if user_id is None:
        as_A = A(user=self)
        as_A.save()
        as_B = B(user=self)
        as_B.save()
```

The only required field in `A` and `B` is `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`, others are optional.

```
class A(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    x = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

class B(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    y = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I want to provide two forms for registration: as A or as B. In registration form as `A`, customer should be able to set fields for `A` model entity related to `User`. Similar for B.

This is my `RegistrationForm`:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords are not same")
        return cleaned_data
```

As you can see it contains only `User` fields.

How to implement properly additional forms and view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MultiModelForm](http://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html?highlight=MultiModelForm#multiform-and-multimodelform) from [django-betterforms](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-betterforms). This will help you achieve what you want to do.